# Adding Gnome Commander to Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

I've installed GNOME Commander to Ubuntu 14.04.01
However, it's not showing up when I search for it in the Launcher.
I'd like to know how to:

1. Add Gnome Commander to the Launcher
2. How to launch Gnome Commander

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNOME commander has a "normal" `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` and should be available in Dash.

You probably just need to log out/in to make it available in Dash. Alternatively: run the command

```
gnome-commander
```

and lock the icon to the launcher. That will work instantly.

[image]